# Using spatial hash to determine view distance

Tags: client-server, character, view, spatial-partitioning

I am creating a client/server that is 2D and based on a map. Characters on the server are then separated into a spatial hash. I am using this to determine who to send data to, essentially, people in your vicinity. I have an issue I am not sure how to resolve.

Let's say my view area is 7x6 grid around the character, with the character being in the center. What I am trying to figure out is how I can keep this grid size even throughout, even when the character is near the edge of the screen.  The way I do this is just convert the character position to a grid position, then check for the grid positions surrounding in that area.

Essentially, I want the viewable area (which is the screen size) to still be a 7x6 grid. The problem is, after implementing, I started getting a lot of sync discrepancies. Something I didn't think of is that this method breaks, because now characters can essentially see beyond their normal range. (see illustration below) It seems a bit unfair to reduce their normal view size just because they are near the edge of the map.

Here is a small grid illustration:
[image]

The lightest colored areas are the view grids, while the darkest are the characters. As you can see in this example, blue characters can see red, but red cannot see blue characters.

Is there another solution I am not seeing here other than just biting the bullet and only letting them see 3 squares away even at the edges?

Answer (score 0):

You are already computing a camera position (position of the "view grid"), which is the same as the character position normally but is different if the character is near the edge.

Instead of using the character position to determine the data you synchronize, use the camera position. That way, you always have data for the visible area.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really that problematic to have the camera scroll past the edges of the map? Giving the "outside area" of the game space a design that looks natural (even though it is inaccessible) is usually a lot less immersion-breaking than the camera suddenly starting to behave differently when the player approaches the map edges.